# How to run multiple lambda functions when deploying as a Docker image?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

How does the `dockerfile` look like for aws lambda with docker image via aws-sam when declaring multiple functions/apps in `templates.yaml`?

Here is the sample `dockerfile` to run "a single app"

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY app.py requirements.txt ./

RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dockerfile` itself looks the same. No changes needed there.

The presence of the `CMD` line in the Docker file looks like it needs to change, but that is misleading. The `CMD` value can be specified on a per-function basis in the `template.yaml` file.

The `template.yaml` file must be updated with information about the new function. You will need to add an `ImageConfig` property to each function. The `ImageConfig` property must specify the name of the function in the same way the `CMD` value otherwise would have done so.

You will also need to update each function's `DockerTag` value to be unique, though this [may be a bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2466).

Here's the NodeJs "Hello World" example template.yaml's Resources section, updated to support multiple functions with a single Docker image:

```yaml
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageConfig:
        Command: [ "app.lambdaHandler" ]
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata:
      DockerTag: nodejs14.x-v1-1
      DockerContext: ./hello-world
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
  HelloWorldFunction2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageConfig:
        Command: [ "app.lambdaHandler2" ]
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello2
            Method: get
    Metadata:
      DockerTag: nodejs14.x-v1-2
      DockerContext: ./hello-world
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

This assumes the `app.js` file has been modified to provide both `exports.lambdaHandler` and `exports.lambdaHandler2`. I assume the corresponding python file should be modified similarly.

After updating `template.yaml` in this way, `sam local start-api` works as expected, routing `/hello` to `lambdaHandler` and `/hello2` to `lambdaHandler2`.

This technically creates two separate Docker images (one for each distinct `DockerTag` value). However, the two images will be identical save for the tag, and based on the same `Dockerfile`, and the second image will therefore make use of Docker's cache of the first image.

Comment: This essentially creates two docker image tags which in long run would be hard to manage. Hopefully the aws sam team will address them soon.

Comment: how would you declare these using serverless framework?